# $s$ is the length of the curve from $O$ to $P$. The tangential force at $P$ is $F(s)$. Does $$m\frac{d^2s}{dt^2}=F(s)$$ hold?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

I am reading "An Introduction to Mechanics" by Daniel Kleppner and Robert Kolenkow.

[image: simple pendulum]

> The sketch shows a simple pendulum of length $l$, with mass $M$, and corresponding weight $W=Mg$.
> The mass moves in a circular arc in a vertical plane. Denoting the angle from the vertical by $\theta$, we see that the velocity is $l\frac{d\theta}{dt}$ and the acceleration is $l\frac{d^2\theta}{dt^2}$. The tangential force is $-W\sin\theta$. Thus the equation of motion is $$Ml\frac{d^2\theta}{dt^2}=-Mg\sin\theta$$ or $$\frac{d^2\theta}{dt^2}+\frac{g}{l}\sin\theta=0.$$

I don't understand the above solution.
The mass doesn't move in a straight line. (The mass moves in a circular arc.)
But the authors derived the differential equation like the above.

Let $s$ be the length of the curve from the vertical to the mass.
Then $s=l\theta$.
Then $$M\frac{d^2s}{dt^2}=Ml\frac{d^2\theta}{dt^2}=-Mg\sin\theta=-Mg\sin\left(\frac{s}{l}\right)$$ holds.

[image]

My question is the following:
Please see the above figure.
The mass $m$ is at the point $P$.
Suppose $s$ is the length of the curve from the point $O$ to the point $P$.
Suppose the tangential force at the point $P$ is $F(s)$.
Does $$m\frac{d^2s}{dt^2}=F(s)$$ hold?

Comment: What are the axes for you graph?

Comment: Perhaps using $\tau = I\,\alpha\Rightarrow -Mg\ell \sin\theta = M\ell^2\frac{d^2\theta}{dt^2}$ assuming circular motion is a clearer approach?

Comment: (Hm, isnt sine$(\frac{s}{l})$ at odds with the definition of a triangle?) The important thing is that Newtons 2. law is defined at a point, and the straight line segment between $l\theta$ and $l(\theta + d\theta)$ can be considered being as close to identical with the arc - segment as you want (since $d\theta$ is infinitesimal)

Answer (score 1):

Your force should explicitly be a function a $(\theta)$ only because it is independent of length of pendulum. So
$$m\frac{d^2s}{dt^2}=F(\theta)$$
where s=$l\theta$ and $F=-mgsin(\theta)$

Answer (score 1):

If a mass is moving on a 2D curve , the mass position (inertial system)   is:

\begin{align*}
  &\vec{P}=\begin{bmatrix}
             x(~q(\tau)~) \\
             y(~q(\tau)~) \\
           \end{bmatrix}
\end{align*}
where q is the generalized coordinate and $~\tau~$ is the time

from here you obtain the velocity $~\vec{v}~$

\begin{align*}
&\vec{v}=\begin{bmatrix}
             x'(q) \\
             y'(q) \\
           \end{bmatrix}\,\dot{q}
\end{align*}
where $~'=\frac{\partial (..)}{\partial q}~$

now the equation of motion , Newton low ,is:
\begin{align*}
 &m\,\frac{d}{d\tau}\left(\vec v\cdot\,\hat{{t}}\right)=\vec{F}\cdot\,\hat{{t}}\tag 1
\end{align*}
where $~\vec{F}~$ is the external force components and $~\hat{t}~$ is the tangent vector at point  $~q(\tau)~$
\begin{align*}
 &\hat{t}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{x'^2+y'^2}}\begin{bmatrix}
             x'(q) \\
             y'(q) \\
           \end{bmatrix}
\end{align*}

**Example: Pendulum**

the generalize coordinate is $~s~$  (not $~\theta~$) thus

\begin{align*}
  &\vec{P}=l\,\begin{bmatrix}
             \sin\left(\frac{s}{l}\right) \\
              -\cos\left(\frac{s}{l}\right) \\
           \end{bmatrix}
   \quad,
   \vec{v}=
   \begin{bmatrix}
      \cos\left(\frac{s}{l}\right) \\
     \sin\left(\frac{s}{l}\right) \\
   \end{bmatrix}\,\dot{s}
   \quad,
   \hat t=\begin{bmatrix}
      \cos\left(\frac{s}{l}\right) \\
     \sin\left(\frac{s}{l}\right)
     \end{bmatrix}
      \quad\text{and}\\
     &\vec{F}=\begin{bmatrix}
                0 \\
                -m\,g \\
              \end{bmatrix}
\end{align*}

with equation (1)

\begin{align*}
  &  \ddot{s}=-m\,g\,\sin\left(\frac{s}{l}\right)
 \end{align*}

**Example: $~\sin~$**

the generalized coordinate is $~x~$ (it doesn't  make sense to choose the line element s to be the generalized coordinate ) thus

\begin{align*}
  &\vec{P}=l\,\begin{bmatrix}
              x\\
              \sin(x)\\
           \end{bmatrix}
   \quad,
   \vec{v}=
   \begin{bmatrix}
      1\\
     \cos(x)\\
   \end{bmatrix}\,\dot{x}
   \quad,
   \hat t=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\cos^2(x)}}\begin{bmatrix}
       1\\
       \cos(x)\\
     \end{bmatrix}
      \quad\text{and}\\
     &\vec{F}=\begin{bmatrix}
                0 \\
                -m\,g \\
              \end{bmatrix}
\end{align*}

the equation of motion is

\begin{align*}
  &\frac{d}{d\tau}\left(\sqrt{1+\cos^2(x)}\,\dot{x}\right)=-m\,g\frac{\cos(x)}{\sqrt{1+\cos^2(x)}}
\end{align*}

this is not what you obtained

**Conclusion**

only if the magnitude of the tangent  vector equal one $~|\vec t|=\sqrt{x'^2(s)+y'^2(s)}=1~$ you obtain
$$\ddot s=x'\,F_x+y'\,F_y$$